# IBOutletCollection Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am trying to reference images stored in an array and then alter properties such as .hidden for my UIImages.

In my .h file I have a `IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *starDisplay;`

Then I linked the pictures via control/drag.

I then want to be able to run a for loop and then `starDisplay[i].hidden = YES;` - but this is coming up with errors.

Any advice (for a new guy so be easy) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you looping through the collection? A code snippet would give more insight.

Comment: what are the errors? please also mention it on question

Comment: The loop is just in my ViewController.m file. Thanks for your help but an answer below got me there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to specify the view which will be hidden. The condition will be changed to

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [starDisplay count]; i++) {
     UIImageView *imageView = [starDisplay objectAtIndex:i];
     [imageView setHidden:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to access the objects in the collection during `viewDidLoad`. It's only at this point will the outlets be set. You can loop through the collection using a basic `for` loop but you will also see the block based enumeration of `NSArray` being used in the wild. The `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method accepts a block as an argument which gives you access to the index, object, and an out parameter to set in the event you want to stop iteration. You're example would look like this:

```
[outletCollection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImageView *imageView, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        imageView.hidden = YES;
    }];
```

The first argument to the block is documented as `id` but you can change it to `UIImageView` so you can set the `hidden` property without Xcode warning.

Also, `NSArray` has a nice method that allows for a one-liner using `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`. The example now looks like:

```
[outletCollection makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@(YES)];
```

When an array receives the `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` it sends the provided selector to each object and uses it's second argument as the sole argument for the sent selector. Since `makeObjects...` is expecting an object, we have to box up our BOOL as an `NSNumber`. It will be unboxed for us when `setHidden:` is called.

Additionally, check out NSHipster for great bits of advice and you can read the article about `IBOutletCollection`s [here](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reponse, much appreciated.